# Android Webview check if element exists

Tags: android

I'm developing a *School meal list application* based on the HTML. The list has tbodys with id and my application checks what day is it and shows only that element. I have my code here:

```
//Get day dd.MM (ex. 01.01)
day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM").format(new Date());

if(webpage..getelementbyid..day.exists..) // Check if element (ex. 01.01) exists.
{
    //There is element with id "01.01"
    list.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.innerHTML=document.getElementById('" + day + "').innerHTML");
} else {
    //There is no element with id "01.01"
    list.loadUrl(noMealToday);
}
```

List (HTML)

```
<tbody id="01.01">
<tr>
...
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I think you can use JSoup to parse the HTML. Its pretty easy to work with JSoup. Give it a try

Comment: I'm looking for something simpler, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old. But, the solution I came up with for this is to use the evaluateJavascript and have it return the innerHTML of the element. If the innerHTML is null or undefined, then you know that it doesn't exist.

```
            mWebview.evaluateJavascript(
                "(function() { var element = document.getElementById('loginStuff'); return element.innerHTML; })();",
                new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String html) {

                        RelativeLayout useVoiceOverlay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.useVoiceOverlay);

                        if( html.equals("null") || html.equals("undefined")){
                            useVoiceOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE );
                        }
                        else{
                            useVoiceOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```